# PHP Cannot redeclare function, previously defined?

Tags: php, sql, web

I'm very new to PHP and I've come across an issue I can't solve. I am trying to create a page that adds a new row to a database. I keep getting an error saying I cannot redeclare the checkIfAdminExists function that's defined in currentSessionData.php (prob gonna rename)

I suspect the issue has something to do with the fact that I'm setting the header location to the current page (create_admin.php) to process form data through POST, and then when the page is loading it's trying to redeclare the function. I've tried including the file inside

if (!function_exists('checkIfAdminExists')),

but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to approach handling form data with a function?

create_admin.php

```
<?php
require_once('currentSessionData.php');

if (isset($_POST['newUsername']) && isset($_POST['newPassword'])) {
    if (checkIfAdminExists($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        // admin account already exists
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("This admin account already exists");';
        echo '</script>';
        header('Location: create_admin.php');
    }
    else {
        //create new admin account in database
        $username = $_POST['newUsername'];
        $password = $_POST['newPassword'];

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
        $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO table_test (username, password)
        VALUES ('$username', '$password')";

    }
}
?>
```

currentSessionData.php

```
<?php

function checkIfAdminExists($username, $password) {
require_once("db_connection.php");
$sql = "SELECT personid, username, password FROM table_test";
$result = $dbcon->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["username"] == $username && $row["password"] == 
$password) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
else {
    return false;
}
$dbcon->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: What line is the error thrown and what is the code on that line?

Comment: Where are you using `function_exists`?

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*`, make use of `mysqli_*` or `PDO` *with* prepared statements.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare checkIfAdminExists() (previously declared in /home/intertid/public_html/currentSessionData.php:3) in /home/intertid/public_html/currentSessionData.php on line 3

Comment: *I keep getting an error saying I cannot redeclare the checkIfAdminExists function that's defined in currentSessionData.php* - Did you try renaming the function?

Comment: This code isn't using function_exists, I just surrounded the code on line 2 of create_admin.php with an   if (!function_exists('checkIfAdminExists')) and it still doesn't work

Comment: You are meant to put the `function_exists` around the declaration of the function.

Comment: Yes, i've tried renaming it. No luck

Comment: Thanks @Script47, that fixed one issue. Unfortunately, now I'm seeing Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/intertid/public_html/create_admin.php on line 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, you are placing the [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) check in the wrong place, change your code to the following:

```
if (!function_exists('checkIfAdminExists')) 
{
    function checkIfAdminExists($username, $password) {
        require_once("db_connection.php");

        $sql = "SELECT personid, username, password FROM table_test";
        $result = $dbcon->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if ($row["username"] == $username && $row["password"] == $password) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        $dbcon->close();
    }
}
```

Now, with the above code, the function will only be defined if it doesn't already exist.

**Note:** Please stop using `mysql_*` as it has been officially deprecated and removed in PHP 7. It would be wise to start learning [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and to make use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

**Update #1**

You are setting the username variable twice:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

It should be:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

**Update #2**

As per the documentation of [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), it takes an optional second parameter:

> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() had been called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

With the above in mind, it means that your connection has not been established. So the next logical question is: Where is your connection being established in `create_admin.php`?

Comment: That's what I've just fixed, but now I'm seeing Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/intertid/public_html/create_admin.php on line 28

Comment: Make sure your connection details / credentials are valid.

Comment: They are. It's telling me the problem is on
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
which doesn't make sense to me since I thought that was just performing some function on a variable and not dealing with the connection

Comment: Do you have a connection variable called `$username` by any chance?

Comment: I do not. $username just stores the username entered through the form through POST.

Comment: wow! I didn't even notice that. I just fixed it and uploaded the new file to the server and I'm seeing the same error after I try to fill out the form. It's still complaining about line 28

Comment: What is line 28 now?

Comment: $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
the next line is the same, but for password

Comment: That error is showing because it cannot find the connection, please see my update.

Comment: I just noticed that a few minutes ago while reviewing my code, I created variables but never tried connecting to the database. I added this code after the $username and $password lines we discussed in create_admin.php

include "db_connection.php";
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO table_test (username, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
$dbcon->query($sqlQuery);
$dbcon->close();

the db_connection file declares $dbcon with mysqli_connect() and passes in my credentials for the database. I use that file with my main login as well, it works fine there

Comment: '*$dbcon with mysqli_connect()*' - You are either using `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*`, which one is it?

Comment: It appears one was using mysqli and the other mysql, that's the result of 2 different tutorials. You said mysql was deprecated, right? This is my first time with anything SQL. I updated all code files to use mysqli and now I get no errors when I submit the form, but no new row is created in the database.

Comment: Use `mysqli_error` to debug your `mysqli` code. Secondly when using `mysqli` AFAIK, you must use the link in the functions if you are using procedural code.

Comment: I just updated that to mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $username); and still no luck. I will debug and read up on some of this stuff so I'm up-to-speed with what I'm coding. Thanks for your help